# Optimal Reading Plan

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is an interview question and not a homework.

"A new feature is to be implemented in Kindle. FEATURE : The user inputs the no. of days in which he would like to complete a particular book and the Kindle will create a reading plan for the user.
Write an algorithm which will output the reading plan to the user. The reading plan should be created keeping in mind that the user would like to begin and end reading a particular “chapter” of the book on the same day."

Now, the reading plan has to be optimal which might mean no. of characters or probably no. of words to be read each day should be as fairly distributed across days as possible.

Now, we don't really know how Kindle stores those books in its backend but I think it would be safe to assume that we can easily get the following data--

1. No. of chapters in the book
2. Start and End point of each chapter
3. No. of pages or No. of words or No. of characters in each chapter or in each page, etc

I am not really able to figure out a concrete solution. Somebody please help.

Comment: This is not really a coding question.  You might want to try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think this is a coding question only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be seen as a variant of line-wrapping. Only here a word is an entire chapter, lines are days, and you don't know the line width (number of words per day) yet.

There are some very different algorithms for it, going from a trivial "fill each line as much as possible" to Dynamic Programming and SMAWK.

You can find the line width by one-sided binary search, you can also estimate it first since it should be close to `total words / days` (certainly no smaller, hopefully not much larger).

It is *not* a variant of the *k*-partition problem, since the chapters (presumably) don't form a set but a sequence, and have to be read in order. The problem is thus only inserting breaks in that sequence, which is much easier.

Comment: If I use Dynamic Programming, how do I define the cost function here?

Comment: @ankitG unused capacity per day squared

Comment: There are two situations right? Because we cannot break the chapters, we might overuse the day or underuse the day.

Comment: @ankitG my original plan was that if you overused a day, the capacity had to be increased. But maybe it's not so bad. Maybe try it both ways.

Comment: How about choosing a line-width here? We can do something like this.. line-width = max(Total words in book / days , max(number of words in each chapter)  ).  So, now we are not worried about overusing and we can simply find optimal(minimal) underuse.

Comment: Also, I think we can come across situations where reading plan may finish before the "asked" number of days. For eg. if there is an insanely huge chapter and because we cannot break it, the line-width then is much greater than the average, hence to minimize "underuse" each day, we might end up coming with a reading plan that finishes before the specified number of days.

Comment: Or shall we ignore overuse and only focus on minimizing underuse? I am a bit confused actually about how to take into account both overuse and underuse together?

Comment: An entire open day is a lot of underuse though, so it would try to avoid that. Anyway, overuse is also minimized, since the square of a negative number (negative leftover capacity) counts just as hard as the square of a positive number.